# Vertical alignment of a formula within an enumeration

Tags: amsmath, enumitem

When typesetting questions and answers for math courses, I often have to use formulae within enumerations. I the following example, I employ the `alignedat` environment to horizontally align the functional equations at the `=` sign. This is why I do not typeset them as separate paragraphs.

[image: example for the alignment problem]

I would like to achieve, however, that the *first* equation is vertically aligned at the enumeration label. In the above example, it should look like

"b) f'(x) = ..."

instead of

"b) f''(x) = ..."

Of course I could fiddle around with `\raisebox{}` to correct for the vertical shift. Does anybody know any solution that works in every such case when combining `enumerate` and `alignedat`?

Here is the MWE for the figure shown above:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\alph*), font=\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some stuff
\item
\begin{math}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
f'(x) &= \dfrac{4 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^2} \\[1ex]
f''(x) &= \dfrac{-12 \, x^2 + 4}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^3} \\[1ex]
f'''(x) &= \dfrac{48 \, x^3 - 48 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^4}
\end{alignedat}
\end{math}
\item Other stuff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the OP clarified that the alignment should be with the first equation, the fix becomes very easy.

**OPTION 1: use `[t]` option**

The `alignedat` environment takes a `[t]` option for specifying top alignment.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\alph*), font=\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some stuff
\item
\begin{math}
\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
f'(x) &= \dfrac{4 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^2} \\[1ex]
f''(x) &= \dfrac{-12 \, x^2 + 4}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^3} \\[1ex]
f'''(x) &= \dfrac{48 \, x^3 - 48 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^4}
\end{alignedat}
\end{math}
\item Other stuff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**OPTION 2: TABstacks**

Use a TABstack in the form of `\alignLongunderstack` in lieu of `alignedat`.  No smashing or special spacing provisions are required.  Note that the `\alignLongunderstack` preserves the inter-equation baselineskip.  If one instead wanted to set a fixed gap between equations, then a `\alignShortunderstack` would be used.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\alph*), font=\sffamily\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some stuff
\item
\ensureTABstackMath{\setstackgap{L}{42pt}
\alignLongunderstack{
f'(x) =& \dfrac{4 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^2} \\
f''(x) =& \dfrac{-12 \, x^2 + 4\dfrac{x^2}{x}}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^3} \\
f'''(x) =& \dfrac{48 \, x^3 - 48 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^4}
}}
\item Other stuff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here it is with a short stack:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\alph*), font=\sffamily\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some stuff
\item
\ensureTABstackMath{\setstackgap{S}{8pt}
\alignShortunderstack{
f'(x) =& \dfrac{4 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^2} \\
f''(x) =& \dfrac{-12 \, x^2 + 4\dfrac{x^2}{x}}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^3} \\
f'''(x) =& \dfrac{48 \, x^3 - 48 \, x}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right)^4}
}}
\item Other stuff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenBSegletes: Thank you very much for your quick reply. You perfectly solved the fine-tuning. My primary intention, however, was to get the label "b)" next to the *first* equation starting with "f'(x) = ". Maybe I should clarify my question above.

Comment: @Matthias Well that makes it real easy.  See my edit.

Comment: @Matthias I edited to give two options: 1) fixed baselineskip between equation baselines (long stack) or 2) fixed gap between equations (short stack).

Comment: @Matthias I also confirmed that `alignedat` takes a `[t]` option that also fixes your problem.